# Paginação dentro de uma div

Tags: php, html

Estou a criar paginação dentro de uma `div` e pretendo que de página em página retorne 5 em 5 linhas, mas não está a funcionar, quando clico para abrir a segunda página não retorna 5 linhas diferentes, só altera a primeira e a última como mostro na imagem:

nesta imagem retorna as primeiras 5 linhas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

nesta imagem retorna quando clico para abrir a pagina 2, onde só altera em relação à anterior a última linha e retira a primeira linha da página anterior:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
<?php
require("conexao.php");
require("init.php");

$itens_por_pagina1 = 5;

$pagina1 = intval($_GET['pagina1']);

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM raddb.Grupo ORDER BY Discricao ASC LIMIT $pagina1, $itens_por_pagina1";

$result1 = $conn->query($query1) or die($conn->error);

$produto1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();

$num1 = $result1->num_rows;

$num_total1 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM raddb.Grupo ORDER BY Discricao ASC")->num_rows;

$num_paginas1 = ceil($num_total1/$itens_por_pagina1);

<div class="table-responsive" id="employee_table1">  
<?php if($num1 > 0){ ?> 
<table class="table table-hover table-striped lista-clientes1">  
<legend><b>Grupos</b></legend>
<tr> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="Filter"></span><input type="text" class="input-search1" alt="lista-clientes1"/>
<th width="25%">Grupo</th>
<th width="30%">Ações</th>                                  
</tr>  
<?php  do{ ?> 
<tr>  
<td><?php echo $produto1["Discricao"]; ?></td>  
<td><button type="button" name="view1" id="<?php echo $produto1["Id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal1" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm view_data1" /><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button></td>
</tr>  
<?php } while($produto1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()); ?> 
</table> 
<nav>
<ul class="pagination">
<li>
<a href="index.php/novoutilizador?pagina1=0" aria-label="Previous">
<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
</a>
</li>
<?php 
for($i=0;$i<$num_paginas1;$i++){
$estilo = "";
if($pagina1 == $i)
$estilo = "class=\"active\"";
?>
<li <?php echo $estilo; ?> ><a href="index.php/novoutilizador?pagina1=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i+1; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
<li>
<a href="index.php/novoutilizador?pagina1=<?php echo $num_paginas1-1; ?>" aria-label="Next">
<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<?php } ?>
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua consulta ao banco de dados, depois do LIMIT você tem dois parâmetros, o primeiro é a posição inicial, o segundo é a quantidade de registros que serão retornados. O problema está no primeiro parâmetro, precisa alterar quando é feita a troca de página, multiplicando o número da página pelo total de registros da página. Aqui tem um exemplo de paginação:

```html
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("host","usuario","senha");
$db = mysql_select_db("bancodedados");
$busca = "SELECT * FROM tabelax";
$total_reg = "10"; // número de registros por página

$pagina=$_GET['pagina'];
if (!$pagina) {
$pc = "1";
} else {
$pc = $pagina;
}

$inicio = $pc - 1;
$inicio = $inicio * $total_reg;
$limite = mysql_query("$busca LIMIT $inicio,$total_reg");
$todos = mysql_query("$busca");
 
$tr = mysql_num_rows($todos); // verifica o número total de registros
$tp = $tr / $total_reg; // verifica o número total de páginas
 

while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($limite)) {
 $nome = $dados["nome"];
 echo "Nome: $nome<br>";
}
 
// Navegação
$anterior = $pc -1;
$proximo = $pc +1;
if ($pc>1) {
echo " <a href='?pagina=$anterior'><- Anterior</a> ";
}
echo "|";
if ($pc<$tp) {
echo " <a href='?pagina=$proximo'>Próxima -></a>";
}
?>
```